# could not find the executable please specify one

Tags: c++, qt, dll, executable

I am trying to create a dll file with C++ using qt.
In my `mylib.cpp` I have:

```
#include "mylib.h"
MyLib::MyLib()
{
}

void MyLib::Test()
{
    qDebug()<<"Hello from DLL!";
}
```

in `mylib.h`:

```
#ifndef MYLIB_H
#define MYLIB_H

#include "mylib_global.h"
#include<QDebug>

class MYLIBSHARED_EXPORT MyLib
{

public:
    MyLib();
    void Test();
};

#endif // MYLIB_H
```

in my `MyLib.pro`:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2015-03-13T15:09:07
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       -= gui

TARGET = MyLib
TEMPLATE = lib

DEFINES += MYLIB_LIBRARY

SOURCES += mylib.cpp

HEADERS += mylib.h\
        mylib_global.h

unix {
    target.path = /usr/lib
    INSTALLS += target
}
```

if I run the project I get such a notification:

[image]

My code does not generate a dll file.

What should I do? how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't run a library, so there's no executable, and the error is fully expected. There's nothing to run. The `dll` certainly gets generated in the build directory. Just go there and you'll find it.

Comment: in the build directory beside my project directory there is no dll file to see. what I see are: `libMyLib.so` , `libMyLib.so.1`, `libMyLib.so.1.0` , `libMyLib.so.1.0.0` , `Makefile` , `mylib.o`

Comment: libMyLib.so is the dll. Dll stands for "dynamically linkable/loadable library". It doesn't need a .dll extension to be one. Dll is a concept, not a file extension nor a file format. And finally, you're on Linux, not Windows.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, How can I Test this dll? I want to see somewhere  `Hello from DLL!`, sorry I am newbie in c++ and...

Comment: @Kaja Create another project that links with that library.